# Should deinit be called in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to find memory issues in my swift app. Found some by checking if deinit is called (strong reference in delegates for example) but checking UITableViewCell's or UICollectionViewCell's I don't see deinit never being called.

I have a really simple cell where I use:

- Some IBOutlets
- Setup view on awakeFromNib (corner radius)
- A setClient function called from tableView with client object to setup view
- prepareForReuse to reset some view parts

Update:

Checked if tableView is calling it's deinit but it's not. So UIViewController calls it's deinit but tableView is still in memory.

Update 2:

Found the issue. A guard let was keeping an strong reference to the tableView in a helper function.

Comment: Cells will not be deallocated until the TableView or CollectionView is deallocated. So the answer to your question depends on when ?

Comment: My UITableViewController calls it's deinit and I even tried setting tableView to nil but cells still don't deinit. Any idea on how to debug where the issue is?

Comment: On my side memory issues were due 3rd-party dependency `Smartlook`. Due this dependency collection view header and some types of cells were not deallocated. Also classes were named not as usual. E.g. `NSKVONotifying_MyCell` instead of just `MyCell`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since tableview cells are reused, they tend to be only deinited if the tableview itself is deinited. Because even if they are not used right now, the tableview would keep them alive in case they are needed for reuse.

Comment: But when table view is deinited all the cells should be deinited too no?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and google lead me here.

I add log to trace that when `deinit` called in UIViewController, which has UICollectionView inside, and when `deinit` called in `UICollectionViewCell`.

Those `UICollectionViewCell` never called `deinit`, and I didn't know why. So, I added more `print("flag1")`, `print("flag2")`, and ... to trace the reason why .....

And then, I figure out the reason. In the cell, a `Timer` is configured for updating itself every 5 seconds. It is the reason why those cells never call `deinit`.

```
fileprivate func configureTimer() {
     self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
          // A code block, for updating cell content.

          // This will keep a strong reference to `self`.
          self.updateUI()
     })
}
```

Finally, I invalidate the timer in `removeFromSuperview` of UICollectionViewCell. I observed that after `deinit` called of UIViewController, the `removeFromSuperview` of UICollectionViewCell will be called.

```
// In UICollectionViewCell
override func removeFromSuperview() {
     self.timer?.invalidate()
     self.timer = nil
}
```

In result, those `UICollectionViewCell` called `deinit` after `UIViewController` called `deinit`.

Maybe, [I should put `[weak self]` in the code block](https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/reasons-for-deinit-is-not-getting-called-ios-swift/) to avoid strong reference inside.